# Lifecycle of Magento CE 1.4.1.1

Tags: upgrade, security, magento-1.4, ce-1.4.1.1

We have a heavily bespoked version of CE 1.4.1.1 and I've looked on the official site but can't seem to find details of any support lifecycle for this version.

Can anyone tell me please whether Magento will continue to offer security updates for this version and if not, when was this version retired, as we will need to scope a project to update to the latest version and migrate the custom extensions to the latest versions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lifecycle of Magento CE 1.4.1.1 was ended when Magento CE 1.4.2.0 was released on December 8, 2010. Furthermore, CE 1.4.2.0 lifecycle was ended February 9, 2011 when CE 1.5 was released. Right now, Magento is on CE 1.9.1.0 that was released on November 24. Currently, you are behind 5 major releases.

Magento usually issues patches just for the Enterprise Edition, as they recommend CE users to upgrade to the next version. Of the rare CE patches that have been released, they seem to be originally designed for the later versions of Magento (however they might work on CE 1.4). To answer your question as to whether or not security updates will continue to be offered for CE 1.4.1.1, the answer is simply **no**. I would recommend to fast-track your project as I already know several critical security issues has already been fixed in later versions. Since Magento is open-source, those issues can be found easily.